# MYSQL Query with OR

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently using the following SQL Query:

```
("SELECT * FROM `form` WHERE '1' IN (show1) AND 'agree' NOT IN (test)")
```

However I can't seem to work out how to add a OR in it.. I need to filter out if it's says 'agree' OR 'disagree'

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking (providing an extract of your table contents and a sample of your desired output might help), but perhaps you want `SELECT * FROM form WHERE show1 = 1 AND test NOT IN ('agree', 'disagree')`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that show1 and test are columns and that this is Mysql related, this should work:

```
"SELECT * 
FROM `form` 
WHERE show1 IN ('1') 
    AND test NOT IN ('agree', 'disagree')"
```

I prefer to have the columns to the left of the comparison :)